# Pause and start Azure analysis service using .net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-analysis-services

Is is possible to start or pause Azure analysis service using .NET SDK?

I want to do this using C#

Comment: now we have requirement to implement azure function APP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have a Nuget package that may work for you.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Analysis/1.1.0-preview